# DELETE tweet in twitter using twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I know ,

Posting twit into twitter  using API ,

But is it possible to delete posted tweet using api ,

Please advise me ,

Thanks

Comment: *(reference)* [Twitter REST API Method: statuses destroy](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses%C2%A0destroy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`statuses/destroy`](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses%C2%A0destroy).  You didn't say which PHP library you're using, but it should have a wrapper for this.  For instance, with twitterlibphp, it's [`destroyStatus`](http://jdp.github.com/twitterlibphp/doc/twitterlibphp/TwitterBase.html#destroyStatus).

Comment: Is it possible to mention which post i want to delete,

Comment: Yes, you pass the id of the post to delete as the argument.